# Sending bytes to POST requests using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I keep on getting the error response 416 when I send post requests to sites. Then when I check the HTML text I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <noscript>
            <title>Pardon Our Interruption</title>
        </noscript>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">

        <style>
            .container { max-width: 800px; margin: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; color: #7a838c; }
            h1 { color: #2a2d30; font-weight: 500; }
            li { margin: 0 0 10px; }
            a { color: #428bca; }
            a:hover, a:focus { color: #2a6496; }
        </style>

        <script>
            function showBlockPage() {
                document.title = "Pardon Our Interruption"
                document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.display = "block";
            }
            setTimeout(showBlockPage, 10000);
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dc/init.js" async defer></script>

        <script>window.addEventListener('load', showBlockPage)</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        

        <div class="container">
            <script>document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.display = "none";</script>

            <h1>Pardon Our Interruption</h1>
            <p>As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:</p>
            <ul>
                <noscript><li>You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.</li></noscript>
                <li>You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.</li>
                <li>You've disabled cookies in your web browser.</li>
                <li>A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this <a title='Third party browser plugins that block javascript' href='http://ds.tl/help-third-party-plugins' target='_blank'>support article</a>.</li>
            </ul>

            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I really don't know the reason why this is happening. I know that error 416 is that the bytes are not being satisfied or something like that. But I don't know why when I see the HTML of the post requests it says another error. Please help. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
    def login(self):
        #1
        headers = {
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'referer': 'https://launches.endclothing.com/distil_r_drop.html',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
        }
        page = self.scraper.get(
            'https://www.endclothing.com/us/',
            headers=headers
        )
        print(page)

        #2
        post = self.scraper.post(
            'https://api2.endclothing.com/us/rest/V1/customers/isEmailAvailable',
            headers={
                'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'origin': 'https://www.endclothing.com',
                'referer': 'https://www.endclothing.com/us/',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
            },
            data={
                'customerEmail': "xxx@yahoo.com"
            }
        )
        print(post)
```

Comment: Please share your python code. Without that, we can't help much.

Comment: Okay I added my code